# iterate over an object retrieved from _.groupBy

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

With the underscore function groupBy, an array can be grouped by one of its element's properties. The result is an object which has key-value pairs as followed: group > corresponding array fragment.

```
var words = ['Hey', 'Hii', 'Salut'],
    grouped = _.groupBy(words, 'length');
```

grouped looks like this:

```
{
  '3': ['Hey', 'Hii'],
  '5': ['Salut']
}
```

Which would be a simple and secure way to iterate over this, say starting with the highest length followed by the next lowest. This works:

```
_.each( _.toArray(grouped).reverse(), function(v) {
  console.log(v);
} );
```

But I think it's not totally correct, because objects are unordered lists, and the right order happens here just by chance.
Any comments on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are right in that you cannot rely on the object keys sorting, you need to enforce the right sorting. With underscore you can use `_.sortBy`:

```
_.each(
    _.sortBy(
        _.toArray(grouped), function (num) {
            return num;
        }
    ).reverse(),
    function (v) {
        console.log(v);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 9):

Due to [ES6's object properties traversal order](http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html), you can directly get the array in the correct order using `Object.values()`:

```js
const words = ['Hombre', 'Muchachu', 'Hey', 'Hii', 'Salut'];
const grouped = _.groupBy(words, 'length');

console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped));

const array = Object.values(grouped).reverse();

console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Old answer:

```
Object.keys(grouped) // get the keys as array
    .sort(function(a, b) { return b - a; }) // sort them from highest to lowset
    .forEach(function(lengthKey) { // iterate the sorted keys' array
        console.log(grouped[lengthKey]); // get the words' arrays by key from grouped
    });
```